# How to write each printed line to a txt file

Tags: python

I have some code that prints information in the terminal currently?. How do I get it to write each line to a txt file as well?

```
def find_bets():
for bet in bets:
    team_name1 = bet[1]
    team_name2 = bet[2]
    league = bet[9]
    lines = [bet[4], bet[5]]
    period = bet[7]
    handicap = bet[6]
    print "-------------------------------"    
    print league
    print game_hour, hours_to_start
    print team_name1, team_name2
    print lines 
    print handicap
    print t1, (game_hour - hours1) / 24.
    print t2, (game_hour - hours2) / 24.
    base_prob = t1 * t2 

    print "BASE PROB", base_prob
```

Comment: Please do some previous research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write both to the output and in the file, you can do

```
f = open("filename", "w")

def print_both(str):
    print str
    f.write(str+"\n")
```

And replace every call to `print` in `find_bets` by a call to `print_both`